# How to perform a rolling/sliding window regression analysis

Tags: r, time-series, regression, linear-regression

This is what I have so far:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)
install.packages("rollRegres")
library(rollRegres)
library(roll)
install.packages("roll")

setwd("C:\Users\timre\OneDrive\Master Thesis")
dataset <- read.csv("rstudiosample.csv")
attach(dataset)
dataset <- is.data.frame(dataset)
window_size <- 20  # Adjust the window size as needed
rolling_data <- rollapply(data = dataset, width = window_size, FUN = function(df) lm(CSAD ~ Sq..Market.return, data = df))
view(rolling_data)

rolling_data <- rollapply(data, width = window_size, FUN = function(df) {
  lm(CSAD ~ Sq..Market.return, data = as.data.frame(df))})
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the following error... :

[image]

I tried to fix the problem:  " 'data' must be a data.frame " but i'm obviously doing something wrong. Please help me out!

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and provide reproducible code as text so others can copy and paste it.  Also the input should be included using `dput`.  For `rollapply` the FUN= arg should be a function which inputs a vector (or matrix if by.column=FALSE) -- not a data frame -- and outputs a scalar or vector -- not an lm object. Use `rollapplyr` with an r on the end if you want right alignment.  Read `?rollapply` carefully.  Here is an example `library(zoo); rollapplyr(mtcars[c("disp", "mpg")], 5, \(x) coef(lm(x[, 2] ~ x[, 1])), by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)`